# How do I extract the numbers after a phrase (xvth) and replace the phrase with "Group-"?

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have data being exported from BigQuery into Google Data Studio one field contains a username like the following.

- **xvth20-00-tt-wr**
- **xvth27-00-pt-px**

The first 4 characters (`xvth`) are always the same and the numbers that follow (`xvth`) correspond to a group. Multiple usernames will contain the same numbers after those characters but the rest of the string from `00-` and on will be different.
What I'm trying to do is extract the numbers that follow the 4 characters and create a new field that looks like the following.

- **Group-20**
- **Group-27**

I've tried the following `REPLACE(SUBSTR(Users,1, 6), 'xvth20', 'Group-20')` and I will have to create one for every condition which seems like too much. Also the data will keep growing so I wouldn't want to keep going in and adding another function.
Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of the below [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) will replace `xvth` with `Group-`, immediately followed by the respective captured numbers; ***Calculated Field #1*** uses a [Raw Literal](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10495775), indicated by the letter `r` which requires a single `\` to escape special RegEx characters whereas ***Calculated Field #2*** requires `\\` to escape a Google Data Studio RegEx as it does not use a Raw Literal:

### 1) With `r` (Raw Literal)

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Users, r"^xvth(\d+).*", r"Group-\1")
```

### 2) Without `r` (Raw Literal)

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Users, "^xvth(\\d+).*", "Group-\\1")
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/fa271407-3ad8-4b8f-8cba-1067bd0bf760) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fEvvyrZXSM8hwFxCjkfQaf5ERauCyQ-3MNYOXeFB96Y/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]